# Javascript not working in div tag when div tag is add after run

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I click and blur div, an other div is create in last, but when I blur div what just is add, javascript not working, please tell me, why? and how fix.

Thanks for advance.
Sample is:
http://jsfiddle.net/a4QNB/420/

js:

```
var contents = $('.changeable1').html();
$('.changeable1').blur(function() {
        $('#addItem').before('<div class=\"changeable1\" contenteditable=\"true\"> Click this div to edit it </div>');
});
```

Comment: Javascript binding for non existent elements does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `div` is getting dynamically added, so try to delegate the `event`.

```
var contents = $('.changeable1').html();
$('body').on('blur','.changeable1',function() {
        $('#addItem').before('<div class="changeable1" contenteditable="true"> Click this div to add an other div </div>');
});
```

Note: You are using jquery 1.6. `on` is not available with this version

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4QNB/425/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, it resolve problem of me, thanks again.